# JQuery Mobile - Refreshing a Button After Changing It's Content

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a reason why the click handler is removed from my button after calling the `button()` method on it. I am changing the content of my buttons, and as a result I need to refresh them. I noticed refresh does not work, so I tried the `button` method.

This will restyle my "button", but I lose my `click` event.

How can I accomplish both?

http://jsfiddle.net/RQZG8/2/

And here is the code:

```js
$("[data-role=button]").html("hello world").button();
$("[data-role=button]").click(function(){
    alert("i have been clicked");
});
```

My big issue is that I have a `div` which is acting as a button. I want to change the content of the `div`, but I want to be able to have it continue to look like a button while keeping it's behavior.

Comment: Your example works no matter how. Please recreate your error in jsFiddle. Also refresh is not working because your button must be initialized prior to refreshing, like this: $("[data-role=button]").html("hello world").button().button('refresh');, But as you probably notices just calling button() is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `$("[data-role=button] .ui-btn-text").html("hello world");` otherwise the padding is lost.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** IMHO, given your example that goes with the question (when you change only caption of a button), there is no much point to use a `div` as a button when jQM gives you a lot of standard choices.

All of these:

```html
<button>Button element</button>
<input type="button" value="Button" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Button" />
```

will be **automatically enhanced by jQM** to buttons without even specifying `data-role="button"`.
And you can of course use a link as a button

```html
<a href="index.html" data-role="button">Link button</a>
```

**Now** if you still want to use your `div` as a button you don't need to specify `data-role="button"` just call `button()` plugin. That will create all necessary markup for you and your original div will be preserved as hidden.

```html
<div id="button1">By button<div>
$("div#button1").button();
```

To refresh a button after you changed its caption you need to call `refresh` method:

```js
$("div#button1").html("Hello World").button("refresh");
```

**Now** to normally handle the click event of a particular button (if it's not the only one on the page) you probably need more specific  selector than just the `data-role=button` attribute. `id` would be perfect for that. So instead of

```js
$("[data-role=button]").click(function(){...});
```

do

```js
$("div#button1").click(function(){...});
```

**And lastly** you most certainly know that, but I didn't see it in your jsfiddle, so I just mention that you better put your code in one of the jQM page handlers. [pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) is recommended way to go.

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    ...
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/q5TnQ/) is jsFiddle.